# How can I filter the results of ListView

Tags: django, python-3.4

I was able to list the results via CBV ListView, but how can I filter it and return only the ages(based on the picture) to ages not exceeding 30 when I click the button!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the get_queryset method in your view. It can be done as follows:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return YourModel.objects.filter(age__lte=30)
```